# Is there a name for a matrix with all zeros on its diagonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Consider a matrix having only zeros on its diagonal, i.e.
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & a & b \\
c & 0 & d \\
e & f & 0 \\
\end{bmatrix}

Has such type of matrices a name?

Comment: Just a side remark: Writing $x,y$ means $x$ may or may not be equal to $y$; hence there is no need to restate $x=y$ is not necessary.

Comment: That's obviously right. I wanted anyway to stress it.

Comment: Diagonull? ${}{}$

Comment: "Scrondo Matrix" sounds equally fine :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually there is a name for this kind of matrix

It is called [Hollow Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hollow_matrix)

Comment: to be honest, I've just googled 'zero-diagonal-matrix' and posted the first result :|

Comment: ...not a mainstream notion though, with ~3500 occurrences in google (and this thread is currently the third one!) :)

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps a *zero-diagonal-matrix*?

Comment: Yeah, that's a Gordian knot :-). I was wondering if there's a more "pictoresque" name,

Comment: Of course. But that's the point: on one hand you already have a compact expression (20 letters) to describe exactly what you want - and that can be even conveniently shortened to ZDM! ;)
On the other hand, not much can be said in general about a ZDM, as each such matrix is the adjacency matrix of a weighted directed graph - whose theory is not quite simple, so I guess nobody ever bothered to invent a name for these objects.

Comment: I like this better; let's rename the wikipedia article from Hollow Matrix to zero-diagonal-matrix.

Answer (score 0):

These are *co-diagonal matrices* according to [Low Rank Co-Diagonal Matrices and Ramsey Graphs by Vince Grolmusz](http://www.emis.de/journals/EJC//Volume_7/PDF/v7i1r15.pdf)..